# Python: Trouble with looping nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, syntax, nested

I want to loop through keys in a dictionary,
and then see if a nested dictionary has a certain value.

However, Im struggling a bit witht he syntax.
This is what I've written:

```
dict = {
    "Bull's eye": {"Points": 50, "Range": 60},
    "Bull": {"Points": 25, "Range": range(55, 59)},
    "Outer value": {"Points": range(0, 20), "Range": range(1, 54)},
}
number = 2
for key in dict.keys():
    if number in dict[key]["Range"]:
        print(f"Value is in {key}")
```

Error: "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable"

Notice that the "number" value is in the "Range" dictionary inside "Outer values".
So when the loop finds this value inside the nested dictionary, I want the if-statement to be True

Comment: why are you naming variables after builtin types? I feel like this is a common thing that should be (heavily) discouraged

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you later do `some_other_fancy_dict = dict()` then you'll instantly run into an error

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the first dictionary you have `"Bull's eye": {"Points": 50, "Range": 60}`. Here, the key is just an int so you cannot use the `in` keyword because an int isn't iterable. If you're using that syntax the dictionary key needs to be an iterable type such as

```
dict = {
    "Bull's eye": {"Points": 50, "Range": (60,)},
    "Bull": {"Points": 25, "Range": range(55, 59)},
    "Outer value": {"Points": range(0, 20), "Range": range(1, 54)},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have different data types for the `Range` field, but the `in` operator assumes an iterable (as produced by the `range` function). You have several options, as pointed out by BTables, you can make sure that your dict only contains iterables - alternatively, you can check for the data type in your loop.

```
for key, value in dict_.items():
    range_ = value["Range"]
    if isinstance(range_, range) and number in range_:
        print(f"Value is in {key}")
    elif isinstance(range_, int) and number == range_:
        print(f"Value equals {key}")
```

Note that I also adjusted the code to use some best practices, such as using a trailing underscore (`_`) in case the name is already a built-in function or reserved keyword (i.e., I renamed your `dict` variable to `dict_`). Also, you can directly loop over the dict's items, instead of only iterating over the keys which made you need to index the dict in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @BTables answer, if you're curious the reason why the error said that is not *iterable* of all things, is because python have several way to solve an `a in B` instruction, first it check if the special method `__contains__` is present in B, and if isn't it will try to iterate over B (aka if it have the special method `__iter__`) and and do a linear search to find the element

```
>>> class A:
        def __iter__(self):
            yield from range(10)

        
>>> a=A()
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x0000027DC8646CD0>
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> 1 in a
True
>>> class B:
        def __iter__(self):
            yield from range(10)
        def __contains__(self, item):
            return False

    
>>> b=B()
>>> 1 in b
False
>>>
```

and the `int` class have neither of those, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this example: (should work as is)

```
dict = {
    "Bull's eye": {"Points": 50, "Range": [60]},
    "Bull": {"Points": 25, "Range": range(55, 59)},
    "Outer value": {"Points": range(0, 20), "Range": range(1, 54)},
}
number = 2
[print(key) for key in dict.keys() if number in dict.get(key).get('Range')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is raising TypeError due to how you are checking the values. Some of the values are integers while others are of the type Range.  You can check if 2 is in a range, but you can't check if 2 is in an integer.

You can use a try/except block to remedy this:

```
my_dict = {
    "Bull's eye": {"Points": 50, "Range": 60},
    "Bull": {"Points": 25, "Range": range(55, 59)},
    "Outer value": {"Points": range(0, 20), "Range": range(1, 54)},
}
number = 2   
for key, sub_dict in my_dict.items():
    try:
        if number in sub_dict["Range"]:
            print(f"number '{number}' is in key '{key}'")
    except TypeError:
        if number == sub_dict["Range"]:
            print(f"number '{number}' is in key '{key}'")
```